# Proving that a function not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $f(x) = x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ using the Sequential Criterion for Absence of Uniform Continuity. So, I found the sequences $(x_n) = n$ and $(y_n) = n+1/n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which satisfy the Sequential Criterion for Absence of Uniform Continuity, so, this means that $f(x) = x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}$.

However, I have to show that $f(x) = x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Would it be valid if I just take $(x_n) = n$ and $(y_n) = n+1/n$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of the sequences I currently have?

**Sequential Criterion for Absence of Uniform Continuity:**

> a function $f:A \rightarrow  $ **R** fails to be uniformly continuous on A iff there exists a particular $\epsilon_0$>0 and two sequences ($x_n$) and ($y_n$) in A, satisfying $|x_n -y_n| \rightarrow 0$, but $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)|\ge \epsilon_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequential criterion does not restrict the conclusion to only the union of the elements in the sequence. You can pick $A=\mathbb R$ and the condition is still satisfied, so it fails to be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ as well.

Comment: Just to be totally clear, I should take $(x_n) = n$ and $(y_n) = n+1/n$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson You can pick $n\in\mathbb N$, since $\mathbb N\subset \mathbb R$. The point is that it fails to be uniformly continuous on the whole domain if there exist two such sequences. If you extended the domain to $\mathbb C$ you could use these same two sequences to show it is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson If you read the criterion carefully, the only thing you need to do is produce the two sequences and show that they satisfy the condition, and you have it on all of $\mathbb R$. There's nothing extra to prove in addition to using the criterion to show that it fails to be uniformly continuous on all $\mathbb R$. If it fails to be uniformly continuous on any part of the domain then it is not uniformly continuous, period.

Answer (score 0):

"so, this means that $f(x) = x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}$." No! Every function on $\mathbb N$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{N}.$ Proof: Given any $\epsilon>0,$ take $\delta = 1/2.$